# Java Process hangs during stdInput reading

Tags: java, oracle, concurrency, process, expdp

I got some problem trying to launch a process that executes an EXPDP command to make the backup of a Oracle DB.

This is the method that launches the process, the problem is when I try to read from stInput and stdError. The process hangs forever, and if I stop the debug to see where the runtime execution is, the line I get is:

```
FileInputStream.readBytes(byte[], int, int) line: not available [native method]
```

At the method entrypoint the value of the cmdCommand parameter is:

```
"EXPDP system/syspwd@orcl DIRECTORY=DATA_PUMP_DIR SCHEMAS=fabro DUMPFILE=backupFabro.dmp LOGFILE=backupFabro.log"
```

The method is the following, and it hangs on the first `while` loop.

```
 public Boolean cmdCommand(String cmdCommand) throws IOException{
            logger.info("**************************************");
            logger.info("Esecuzione comando:");
            logger.info(cmdCommand);
            logger.info("**************************************");
            final Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdCommand);
            Boolean end = false;
            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
            String line = null; 
            try {
                while ((line = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                    logger.info(line);
                }
                while((line= stdError.readLine()) != null){
                    logger.error(line);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            }
            finally{
                stdError.close();
                stdInput.close();
            }
            try {
                if(p.waitFor() != 0){                       
                    logger.error("error etc etc");
                }
                else{
                    end = true;
                    logger.info("success ecc ecc");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
                p.destroy();
            }
            return end;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using  .ready()  function.

```
try {
      if (stdError.ready()) 
      {
            while((line= stdError.readLine()) != null){
                logger.error(line);
            }
      }
}
```

Do the same for the stdout.

It worked like a charm for me.